# How to import excel and validation data in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, excel

I'm working a project and my task have some followings require:

- Import a excel file and show data in HTML table before submit
- Show error in each cells in HTML table before submit, and if row have any error in any cell, this row will be have red color.
  So, I want to collect your idea. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

to get the data from excel file you can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file library.
store the data in state and present in the table as you do in html.

Comment: But I want validate data and show error in each cells

Comment: can u explain more in detail like when you want to show the error